# Best practice to use pyo3-polars with `group_by`

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars, pyo3

I'm currently in the process of experimenting with [pyo3-polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars) to optimize data aggregation. In a more abstract sense, what I have in mind is the following structure:

```py
df.group_by(c.col1).agg(c.col2.foo())
```

Here, `foo` represents a nontrivial function that produces a `f64` result. To provide a more concrete explanation, the function `foo` can be illustrated by the following pseudocode:

```
agg = 0.0
for i in 0..len(col2):
    for j in i+1..len(col2):
        func(agg, col2[i], col2[j])
return agg
```

The current implementation I have is designed to return a `Series`:

```rust
#[polars_expr(output_type=Int64)]
fn int_agg(inputs: &[Series]) -> PolarsResult<Series> {
    let ca = inputs[0].i64()?;

    let mut v = Vec::new();
    let mut tot: i64 = 0;

    for i in 0..(ca.len()) { // Fake approximation of actual task
        unsafe {
            tot += ca.value_unchecked(i); 
        }
    }
    v.push(tot);
    let out: Int64Chunked = v.into_iter().map(|i| Some(i + 2)).collect_ca(ca.name());
    Ok(out.into_series())
}
```

However, I have significant reservations about whether this is the most optimal approach for this particular task. All the examples shown in the repository returns `PolarsResult<Series>` which forces to create a Series containing a single element. Later in the python session, I had to serially call `foo().first()` to get the element due to this artifical constraint. Is there a better alternative that directly returns a single element?

Moreover, I am potentially interested in a more comprehensive solution where the aggregation function accepts multiple columns, such as `df.group_by("col1").agg(foo("col2", "col3"))`.

Comment: There are some multiple column examples in https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars/blob/main/example/derive_expression/expression_lib/src/expressions.rs

Comment: @jqurious Maybe I was nor clear in the question. The main question was whether returning series as illustrated above is the right way to do for this kind of tasks. Because in this example, I had to create a vector from a single element just to satisfy the function signature. If I understand correctly, all the examples shown on your link return 'PolarsResult<Series>', which seems too constraining.